# Rendered animation is incomplete

Tags: rendering, animation, keyframes

So I'm having an issue with the animation I am doing atm. It is as many frames as shown in the image, but for some reason when I am rendering, the animation suddenly stops just before the gap in the animation which is when the camera is moving. I tried it again just in case I pressed esc by accident but it still did the same thing. I tried just moving a random bone in case it needed something moving other than the camera but it didn't work. I've never had this issue before in my previous animations, just for this one. I thought I would try and start it at the point it stopped and continue the rendering but, when I do that it just goes straight back to the beginning of the part I've already rendered.

Am I doing something wrong? Please help! Thanks! :D My Blender version is 2.74

[image: Normal key frames]

Then when I try to get rid of the beginning part...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using a separate timing for the playback ( time line ) and the render ( render tab ) you have two options to render the frames you want :

1- Keep the timing separate and set the render timing in the render tab :

[image]

2- Use the same timing for playback and render by disabling the ***alternative time range*** and set the time from either the render tab or the time-line 
[image]

Comment: @user14621 you can click check-mark to indicate that the problem is solved : )