# I can't render past frame 35!

Tags: rendering

Whenever I render an animation I have downloaded and edited it wont render past frame 35. It stops, freezes on me then I have to open it back up again! But when I attempt to make my own, (thats why I download templates I cant animate...) It does... What is a possibility or the problem? I need this fixed ASAP! I'm making this for a client and I cant have a bad rep!

[image]

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31486/rendered-animation-is-incomplete

Comment: and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8898/how-do-you-select-only-part-of-a-timeline-to-be-rendered/8902#8902

Comment: Is it possible you could upload a screenshot or .blend?

Comment: Perhaps an obvious thing to check, but always worth noting, did you check the end frame was not set to 35?

Comment: I did check the end frame... I've check as many stuff as I remembered... I even went to see if res could affect rendering...

Comment: and i dont know how to upload a screenshot. This is my first time having this big of a problem...

Comment: Can you edit your question to be more clear about what happens after frame 35? Do you get the same frame over and over? Do you get blank frames? Does rendering totally stop and not produce any more images?

Comment: ...a bigger image would also be nice, if you can upload it. This resolution makes it difficult to read what any of your settings are.

Comment: is VSE a type of rendering engine? I cant find it! in blender 2.70

Comment: The VSE isn't so much an engine as it is Blender's Video Editor.  Also does this problem persist if you open the .blend on the latest version of Blender? (2.77a)

Comment: Didnt think of reinstalling on version 2.77 trying it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Blender is freezing and crashing while you're rendering, then the animation is doing something that demands more resources than Blender is able to give it.

Without being able to see the file, it's really hard to guess. There are a number of things that might be going on at frame 35. At that point, there are some keyframes. These keyframes might be related to something very complex going on. There might be a whole lot of objects introduced into the scene at that point, which would increase the RAM requirement. There might be some kind of feature introduced at that point, that Cycles isn't able to handle.

It looks like this scene might be trying to use Animation Nodes, which aren't supported in 2.70.

Generic solutions are few and far between, but one of them is upgrade Blender to the latest release (the one on Blender.org, not from the nightly builds). Don't try to solve anything else until you've upgraded.

The next thing you need to do is find out what NEW thing the scene is trying to do at frame 35.

- Look in the Visual Sequence Editor to see if there's a new effect or strip that starts at frame 35.
- Look in the Graph Editor and/or Dope Sheet to see if there are any animations that start on frame 35.
- Look in the Compositor to see if there are any nodes that have keyframes. Maybe there's a compositing thing that starts at frame 35.
- Look in the Console (Windows -> Toggle System Console) to see if it's giving you any error information that might help.
- Look in the Info panel (blue circle with an 'i'; it looks like it's just a menu bar, but drag its border to make it bigger) to see if there are any errors there that might help.

On an unrelated note, if you've gotta deliver this to a client, you don't have time to solve this problem. You've run into this problem already. It's likely that you'll run into more problems with the same file, even if you solve this one. You need to dump this file and go find another solution.

Comment: Nodes disapeared in new version of blender, but switching fixed it! My Desktop PC has enough RAM, but I guess it was adding something in it didnt have in 2.70