# (Blender Internal) How to time Cell Fracture?

Tags: animation

I have a really simple question that I've needed the answer to for a while now but couldn't find it. Is there a way to make the Cell Fracture times longer? What I mean is that is there a way I can maker it last longer then stopping at the 250 mark on the timeline? Thank you!

Comment: related : [https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31486/rendered-animation-is-incomplete/31487#31487](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31486/rendered-animation-is-incomplete/31487#31487), maybe duplicated.

Comment: Oh my god it isn't. I'm talking about making the Cell Fracture longer, that question is asking about the timeline itself.

Comment: And did you try to just increase your timeline?

Comment: As far as I remember, Cell Fracture can utilize Particle System. So, default Particle System has emitting end frame at 200 and lifetime for another 50 frames. That is exactly 250 frame limit you have. Just go to Particle settings and change frame bounds.

Comment: If your cell fracture is using rigid body physics, you could decrease​ the speed of the rigid body simulation I believe in the 'rigid body world' settings, under the scene tab.

Comment: Ah I found it, under Rigid Body Cache. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Properties Editor Type, in Scene context, check Rigid Body World on. Once done, go to the Cache options, and set the amount of the cache stored for your simulation, usually the same amount of the Time line, i.e. if you increase the number of frames on the Time Line, do the same in Cache options. [image]